# Razor, how to cache an ITemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, razor

I am using RazorEngine to render templates (that we use as newsletter).
A nice thing with RazorEngine 3 (https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) is that you can use:
- Template layouts
- Include templates

For this to work however you need to make a dynamic resolver service.

This resolves and returns me the full template, as a compiledRazorTemplate:

```
ITemplate rTemplate = service.Resolve(templateId, parameters);
```

Then I do rTemplate.Run()

Which invokes:

```
public static string Run(this ITemplate template)
{
    ExecuteContext context = new ExecuteContext();
    return template.Run(context);
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't cache my templates! And I really need to cache them.
but Razor.Parse(template, model, cacheName) only accepts string templates.

How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

There is little point caching the an instance of an `ITemplate` instance, if you run an instance multiple times you'll likely have issues with it's output. When you use `Resolve(name)`, it uses your `ITemplateResolver` to locate the template content, it then compiles that template. As you've provided a name, it will then cache the template `Type` against that name. Subsequent calls to `Compile(name)`, and `Resolve(name)`, etc, will result in the existing named template type being used, instead of recompiling the template again.